Issues using epstopdf OSX + TexStudio
TexStudio 4.8.4  OSX 14.12.1
Basically the issue is that I cannot get TexStudio to run in such a way that I am able to automatically convert included eps files to pdf during compilation. Ultimately the log file suggests that epstopdf creates the 'filename-converted-to-pdf.pdf' file but I cannot find it anywhere in my machine. I've been banging my head against this for a few weeks now.  Ghostscript is installed, as is epstopdf.
For exact way to reproduce see minimum viable script below
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{suffix=}

\begin{document}
    test\\
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{testeps.eps}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}

I end up with the error '! Package pdftex.def Error: File `testeps.pdf' not found: using draft setting.'

Welcome to TeX.SE. Does it work when you run pdflatex yourfile.tex from the terminal instead of through TexStudio? Does it work with just \usepackage{graphicx} without \usepackage{epstopdf}?

I cannot get pdflatex to run in the terminal, I believe this is setup issues and will look into it.
It does not work with either \uspackage{} format you suggested.

Can you show the first few lines of your .log file?

you should not need epstopdf package or \epstopdfsetup unless you have  a very old latex (20 years or so)

as a test you can also use \includegraphics{testeps} (missing out the extension is adviasable anyway and then mak ethe pdf by rinning epstopdf testeps.eps on the terminal which will make a pdf file which pdftex can include
